# Gulp. Само тело task'а выполняется первым, чем массив task'ом второго аргумента. Почему?

Tags: gulp

```
gulp.task('connect', () => {
    connect.server({
        port: 8000,
        livereload: true,
        root: './dist'
    });
});

gulp.task('sass', () => {
    gulp.src('./sass/**/*.sass')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
});       

gulp.task('concatcss', ['sass'], () => {
    gulp.src('./css/**/*.css')
        .pipe(concatcss('main.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css/'))
        .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('watch', () => {
    gulp.watch('./sass/**/*./sass', ['concatcss']);
})
```

При изменении файлов ./sass/main.sass с файлом ./dist/css/main.css НИЧЕГО не происходит. НО если сохранить второй раз, то все так, как и должно быть. Мне кажется, проблема в том, что `concatcss` срабатывает первым. Так как с файлом ./css/main.css все как полагается.

Что не так с gulpfile'ом?

Comment: Пишите return перед gulp.src... !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Здесь у тебя выполняются две задачи на одну сущность.
Лучше склеить это все (приведу пример из своего `gulpfile.js`

var config = {
  scss    :[ 'src/scss/**/*.scss' ],
  css     :[ 'src/css/' ],
  src     :[ 'src/' ],
  //etc.........
};

gulp.task('styles',function(){
  return gulp.src(config.scss)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass()
    .on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 3 versions'))
    .pipe(minifycss())
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(''+config.css+''))
    .pipe(reload({stream:true}));
});
```